# Django: extend overridden template

Tags: python, django, django-templates, modularity, django-apps

I have two applications in my settings.INSTALLED_APPS:

```
INSTALLED_APPS = [
    'application2',
    'application1'
]
```

and want application2 to change a template from application1 (e.g. by adding a button).

How can achieve this without overriding the whole template?

**NOTE**

The problem is that the two templates have the same name ("mytemplate.html") and the same folder name ("application1"):

```
\project_root
    \application1\templates\application1\mytemplate.html
    \application2\templates\application1\mytemplate.html
```

so that I cannot write:

```
{% extends "application1\mytemplate.html" %}
```

because both templates are named "application1\mytemplate.html".

Answer (score 2):

I don't think this is possible for the case you describe because it implies that INSTALLED_APPS order matters. As it is [stated in the django book](http://www.djangobook.com/en/2.0/chapter06/):

> **The order of INSTALLED_APPS doesn’t matter**, but we like to keep things alphabetical so it’s easy for a human to read.

I understand that this is not the official documentation. However the book is authored by Adrian Holovaty and Jacob Kaplan-Moss (the Django creators), so I'll take their word on it.

But if you think a bit about it you will see why ordering is not such a great idea:
It only helps in specific - easy cases. In slightly more complex cases it wouldn't help. E.g.:

- You have `app1`, `app2`, `app3`.
- Both `app2` and `app3` extend/override templates `app1/a.html` and `app1/b.html`.
- You want to use `a.html` as defined in `app2` and `b.html` as defined in `app3`.

Comment: There are django applications (e.g. django-grappelli: http://readthedocs.org/docs/django-grappelli/en/latest/quickstart.html#setup) which are to be inserted in INSTALLED_APPS before other applications, so that they can override default behaviour.

Comment: I'm aware that apps that rely on INSTALLED_APPS order do exist. But they are definitely corner cases. E.g. django-grappeli makes substantial modifications to the django admin interface. From a functionality perspective, django-grappeli is more of a django mod than a django app.
Relying on INSTALLED_APPS order is definitely not a good Django practice for your everyday app.

Answer (score 1):

I don't think it is possible, unless you have different template names, then you can use {{ block.super }}

Once loader finds correct file, it doesn't look any further, so you don't have an access to overridden template in your new template.

https://code.djangoproject.com/browser/django/trunk/django/template/loaders/app_directories.py#L57

Answer (score 1):

Templates aren't really owned by applications. They can be grouped into application directories if you like, but are pretty much independent of them.

The way to override part of a template, whatever application provided it, is to inherit from it using `{% extends 'template_name.html' %}` and then define whatever blocks you need to override. Of course, this means that the parent template will need to have those blocks already defined - otherwise you'll need to override the smallest relevant block that is defined, and repeat some of the content around the bit you need to change.

Comment: The problem is that the two templates have the same name. I've added this note to the question.

Comment: So don't name them the same? That won't work anyways. Django will *always* just pull the first template it finds with the specified name, so the template for whichever app is lower in INSTALLED_APPS will never be used.